# Is there any difference between saying "for long" or just "long"?

Tags: grammaticality

For example:
Is "Good sensation of freshness long after brushing" any different from "Good sensation of freshness for long after brushing?"

Comment: In this context no, because it's talking about something lingering. But _long after brushing_ refers to a point of time, while _for long after brushing_ refers to a period. Though in my idiolect, I would not say _for long after brushing_: I would say _for long_ (though normally only in the negative). But if I wanted to qualify it I'd say _for a long time after brushing_.

Comment: Which phrase did the advertising agency pick?

Answer (score 1):

The first is better, the second sounds disjointed.
*long after brushing* refers to not a point in time, but the passage of a period of time.  Meaning the sensation of freshness will last a long time after you brush.

As another example, you would say:

> We will remember her long after she's gone.

but probably not:

> We will remember her for long after she's gone.

Preceding the time period with *for* would be more appropriate if you were referring to a specific amount of time:

> The sensation of freshness will last for 10 minutes after you brush

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically speaking yes, it depends where you place it on the sentence, which although it may not necessarily change the meaning, it will sound strange to the listener; as such I would not try to leave it standing alone, I would put *time* next to it, so:

> Good sensation of freshness a long time after brushing